# How to Add a Column to BigQuery External Table

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a bunch of data stored in partitioned ORC files in Google Cloud Storage.  My bucket looks something like the following:

```
my_bucket
- folder_of_orc_files
- - partition1=abc
- - - file1.orc
- - - file2.orc
```

I have an external table defined in BigQuery that points to the data above that was created like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE my_dataset.my_external_table
WITH PARTITION COLUMNS (
  partition1 STRING, 
)
OPTIONS (
  uris=['gs://my_bucket/folder_of_orc_files/*'],
  format=orc,
  hive_partition_uri_prefix='gs://my_bucket/folder_of_orc_files'
);
```

Those files currently have columns "Column A", "Column B" and "Column C".

Now I need to add "Column D".  So I add a file3.orc that contains "Column D".  In reality, of course, I have a metric ton of files and would rather not have to recreate all of the old ones. I need a way to have the external table see "Column D" with NULLS for the old entries and with the proper values from the new files.

Out the door, the external table does not see "Column D".  So I dropped the table and re-added it.  It still only has columns A, B and C and completely ignores "Column D".  With ORC files you cannot specify schema - it reads it automatically.  The ALTER TABLE command does not work for external tables.

The only thing I have found (short of reloading all of the data from scratch from my Spark jobs) is that I could move all of my data in to temporary tables and then re-write them out - which is again quite a large task (and expensive) when you have a huge amount of data.  Anyone know of any other way to achieve this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you ask BigQuery to perform a schema autodetect, BigQuery simply get a sample of lines (for CSV, or JSON format). For binary files, such as ORC format, I guess it's a sample of files, or the first one get.

Anyway, after the schema definition, the schema is never updated automatically. If you r format change, you have to update it manually.

Indeed, you can't do it with an  `ALTER TABLE` statement, but you can do it on the UI or with the bq CLI (or the API/client libraries if you prefer). You have the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#adding_columns_to_a_tables_schema_definition)

So, not impossible, but not automatic!

Comment: Thank you!  The "Edit Schema" button is scrolled out of view, so it's not obvious.  But you are correct, it is there if you go looking for it.  I'll take this as a win.  I can scroll down on a window to avoid data reloads, no problem.  Much appreciated!